# using csvhelper writer with shouldquote in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, csvhelper

I can see how shouldquote works with c# but does anyone have an example in vb.net?

I need to wrap every field with chr(34)

Comment: Every Field Type, or just strings? Including the Header? Should booleans, if any, serialize as  `"True"` and `"False"`? -- You also need to specify the CsvHelper version in use.

Comment: I was just asked to "quote everything"! It wouldn't surprise me if once they see it, they decide that's not what they wanted though......  I am using v27.1.1. it would be useful to see how to be more specific about what gets quoted, and to convert boolean to True/False etc. as there are hardly any vb.net examples around.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Private Sub Main()
    Dim records = New List(Of Foo) From {
        New Foo With {
            .Id = 1,
            .Name = "one"
        }
    }
    
    Dim config = New CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) With {
        .ShouldQuote = Function(args) True 
    }

    Using csv = New CsvWriter(Console.Out, config)
        csv.WriteRecords(records)
    End Using
    
End Sub

Public Class Foo
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
End Class
```